# Как проверить работоспособность рекламы в xcode и testflight?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

После отключения рекламы Google не могу понять, как проверить работоспособность рекламы.
В xcode меняю язык и регион - не показывает.
Открываю в Testflight - не показывает.
Использую рабочую версию, где 100% сейчас реклама работает и доход с неё идет, но в тестовых приложениях и в симуляторе нет возможности проверить.
Помогите кто знает какие еще способы есть. Спасибо!

Comment: Тестовую рекламу пробовали включать? https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads

Comment: Нет, нужно будет попробовать. Пока спас VPN на телефоне, смог проверить :D